# Вставлять информацию о статусах отслеживания в расширение

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется сайт отслеживания ДпД: https://www.dpd.ru/. Задача в том, чтобы брать информацию с сайта и копировать данные в расширение. Человек переходит на сайт отслеживания по ссылке: [https://www.dpd.ru/ols/trace2/standard.do2?orderNum=ТРЕКНОМЕР](https://www.dpd.ru/ols/trace2/standard.do2?orderNum=%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A0). Получает таблицу со статусами. Нужно по нажатию на кнопку расширения вставлять данные: https://prnt.sc/qzospz. И получать в окне расширения готовый текст:По последнему отслеживанию на 05.02.2020, статус заказа «Осуществляется доставка получателю». Просьба помочь в решение или натолкнуть на пути решения вопроса.

```html
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
 
    "name": "DPDBETA",
    "description": "Берем информацию о статусах ДПД",
    "version": "1.0",
 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
        <title>DPDotsl</title>

    </head>
    <body>
По последнему отслеживанию на ЧИСЛО, статус заказа «СТАТУС».
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Тоесть выходит Вы даже не попытались сделать сами? Во-первых за Вам никто делать полностью не будет, это не сайт выполнения задач. Во-вторых ссылку, которую Вы предоставили https://www.dpd.ru/ols/trace2/standard.do2?orderNum=ТРЕКНОМЕР - вот как мы сможем узнать где там на странице вообще находятся статусы и в каком виде? По картинке этого точно не понятно, ни тегов, ни разметки, ничего.

Comment: Хотите, чтобы Вас направили? Так при запросе парсите сайт, вытаскивайте данные и передавайте данные в свой код расширения. Больше тут увы ничего не скажешь учитывая предоставленные данные...